# Borderless NSTextField with a 6px border-bottom?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview, nstextfield

Is it somehow possible to subclass NSTextField, and add a 6px border to the bottom side only? The other sides should be borderless. No shadows, no anything.

I tried replicating this with a NSView subclass 6px high instead (so 2 separate objects), but the view is drawing itself too much when I'm scrolling fast, there seems to be some kind of lag (though I do nothing more than NSRectFill([self bounds]).

That's why I want to subclass NSTextField instead.

Comment: Did you try nesting it? First add a UIView which is 6px higher than the UITextField. Then add the UITextField (at 0/0) as subview to it. Let the UIView have the same background colour as the UITextField has and it should look fine - even when scrolling fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSTextField's drawing is actually done by an instance of NSTextFieldCell, so that's what you want to subclass, and the method you want to override is `-drawInteriorWithFrame:inView:`. Setting the cell class of a text field in a .xib file is a bit of a pain, but you can do it by looking through the view hierarchy, expanding the arrow next to the text field, and selecting the cell there, and then setting its custom class.